# gdb debugging - only \n inside stdin

Tags: c, windows, command-line, terminal, gdb

I'm debugging my program in windows with GDB and need stdin.
So, I compiled it :

```
gcc -g abstieg2.c
gdb a

break 1
run < graph1.in
```

But the stdin has only \n in it!

```
do{
    getline(&line,&size,stdin);
} while(!strcmp("\n",line)); // for testing, gets stuck forever, but only with gdb
```

I really can't see what more can be relevant to this problem.
Thanks

stripped down version of my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <limits.h>

void *errorchecked_malloc(unsigned int);
unsigned int correctinput(char**);
void free_us();
void my_qsort(int , int r);
unsigned int *Dijkstra(int , int , unsigned int , int );
unsigned int min_distance(unsigned int* , int );
int linearsearch(int);
char* strerror(int);

unsigned int *start_edge=NULL; // Input of edges is organised into three array
unsigned int *end_edge=NULL;
unsigned int *length_edge=NULL;
unsigned int *base_camp=NULL ; // Input of basecamps
unsigned int *Dijkstra_dist=NULL; // distance value of dijkstra algorithm
unsigned int *Dijkstra_vis=NULL; // visited by dijkstra algorithm?
unsigned int *Dijkstra_predec=NULL ; // predecessor of dijkstra algorithm
unsigned int* found=NULL;

int * pos_in_vertices;
char* store_for_reset= NULL; // line (input) char* wil be changed, in store_for_reset line will be saved
int basecamp_length=0;

/*Aim: Find the shortest way in a graph from start_vertices to finish_vertices
 * restrictions:
 * -2 Day travel with max_distance per day
 * -after one day a basecamp must be reached( or the finish vertices)
 * -N vertices <=N
 *
 * Input is organized as following:
 * start_vertices finish_vertices d_max\n //
 * start_vertices end_vertices max_distance\n // for each edge
 * ...
 * base_camp\n
 * base_camp\n
 * ...
 */

int main( ) {
    int N=0;  // count of vertices
    int arg_line_count=0; //

    unsigned int start; // First three Input of start basecamp
    unsigned int end; // finish basecamp
    unsigned int d_max; // maximum travel distance per day

    char* line = (char *)errorchecked_malloc(36*sizeof(char));
    store_for_reset= line;
    int size =strlen(line);
    //Input configuration
    do{
        getline(&line,&size,stdin);
        printf("%s",line);
    } while(!strcmp("\n",line));// for testing, gets stuck forever, but only with gdb
    start_edge = (int*)errorchecked_malloc(sizeof(int)*1000); // creating space, TODO dynamic space allocation
    end_edge = (int*)errorchecked_malloc(sizeof(int)*1000);
    length_edge = (int*)errorchecked_malloc(sizeof(int)*1000);

    start = correctinput(&line); // first line input
    end = correctinput(&line);
    d_max = correctinput(&line);

    // input of all edges

    for(int i=0;fgets(line,size,stdin);i++){ // fgets returns NULL if stdin empty
        printf("Zeile %d \n", i);
        start_edge[i]=correctinput(&line);
        printf("line: %s", line);
        if(line[0]=='\0'){ // end of line, means now are only basecamps left
            base_camp[0]=start_edge[i];
            start_edge[i]=0;
            basecamp_length=1;
            break;
        }
        if(start_edge[i]>N) N= start_edge[i];
        end_edge[i]=correctinput(&line);
        length_edge[i]=correctinput(&line);
        line =store_for_reset;

    }




    // Input of basecamps
    base_camp= (int*)errorchecked_malloc(sizeof(int)*N); // generous, N is maximum of Nodes

    for(int i=1;fgets(line,size,stdin);i++){
        base_camp[i]=correctinput(&line);
        if(line!=NULL){
            printf("fatal error:Too many arguments per line while reading \"Basislagern\" input");
            free_us();
            exit(-1);
        }
        basecamp_length++;
    }
    free_us();
}

unsigned int correctinput( char** string){
    char* test;
    unsigned int tmp =strtol(*string,&test,10);
    if((test[0]!=' ' && test[0]!= '\n' ) ||  errno != 0 ) {
        printf("Don't mock me! Please use the correct input format. \n Information: ");
        strerror(errno);
        printf(" Next Character: \'%d\'", atoi(test));
        free_us();
        exit(-1);
    }
    //printf("test: %s, /n",test);
    int i;
    for(i=0;(*string)[i]>='0' && (*string)[i]<='9';i++){
        *string=(*string)+ i*sizeof(char); // moves the input pointer to the next argument( therefore pointer to pointer)
    }
    if(*string[i]==' ')string++;
    return tmp;
}

void free_us(){
    free(start_edge);
    free(end_edge);
    free(length_edge);
    free(base_camp);
    free(Dijkstra_dist);
    free(Dijkstra_vis);
    free(pos_in_vertices);
    free(Dijkstra_predec);
    free(store_for_reset);
    free(found);
}

void *errorchecked_malloc(unsigned int size){
    void *ptr;
    ptr = malloc(size);
    if(ptr == NULL) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Error: could not allocate heap memory. \n");
        free_us();
        exit(-1);
    }
    return ptr;
}
```

Input looks like this:

```
0 1 3924456639
0 5 1268156980
0 18 293858388
0 74 142402607
1 4 145988610
....
24
1
27
79
4
70
...
```

Comment: What is in `graph1.in`? What do you want to do?

Comment: show full code.

Comment: Windows newline is `\r\n`(`0d 0a`), not `\n`. I am not sure whether standard library stdin will automatically convert between the two.

Answer (score 0):

You are probably hitting this Windows specific gdb bug:
https://www.cygwin.com/ml/cygwin/1999-04/msg00308.html

Try to upgrade to a latest version of gdb (8.0 as of now).
Among other things there were some enhancements for debugging on MS-Windows in this release. See in [NEWS file](https://sourceware.org/git/gitweb.cgi?p=binutils-gdb.git;a=blob;f=gdb/NEWS;hb=HEAD):

```
  55 * Native debugging on MS-Windows supports command-line redirection
  56 
  57   Command-line arguments used for starting programs on MS-Windows can
  58   now include redirection symbols supported by native Windows shells,
  59   such as '<', '>', '>>', '2>&1', etc.  This affects GDB commands such
  60   as "run", "start", and "set args", as well as the corresponding MI
  61   features.
```

Comment: So, I tried to install 8.0, but because there is no pre build version, I Installed mysys and tried to build it ./configure went well but while making it this error shows up:   
'cli-script.o:c:/mingw/include/stdio.h:427: first defined here
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status'  
I reinstalled mingw but it changed nothing.   
Thank you very much for helping me

Comment: See discussion of this issue here: https://sourceforge.net/p/mingw/mailman/message/35857678/. Hope it will help.